# Science fiction book about world overrun by grass

Tags: story-identification, books

It was a great book done as an anti-version of Christopher's *The Death of Grass*, with a touch of black comedy.

The story was about a botanist working on a formula to improve crop yields and a stupid salesmen causes the formula to be released and it affects grass in the cracks of the street.

Within days there is a hundred foot high tuft of grass turning into a jungle that begins sweeping across the US and eventually the planet, resistant to man and bomb and all tools imaginable.

It ends on a research boat at sea where they are desperately hunting the cure, but all goes wrong again....

Comment: Surely the key would be to breed a 250ft high atomic lawnmower.

Comment: Similar idea to that one with the cure for the common cold, ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's *[Greener Than You Think](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/m/ward-moore/greener-than-you-think.htm)* by Ward Moore, published in 1947. Actually, way before Christopher's *The Death of Grass*, that was published in 1956.

> Written in 1947, a science fiction novel about the grass we tread upon. When an unscrupulous salesman sprays a dying suburban Los Angeles lawn with an untested chemical spray, it is the beginning of the end of the world. The grass begins to grow uncontrollably and riotously, ten feet hight, thick, tough, inpenetrable, gradually engulfing Los Angeles, then California..After reading this novel, you will never view your lawn in the same way.

It can be downloaded from Project Gutenberg for free: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/24246

Comment: Thank you so much! That has been bugging me for ages. Can't wait to reread - you've made my week!

Comment: So very glad that I did! Seems like you’ve already started (re)reading this book, so it looks like it’s unnecessary to edit my answer: I hope you’ll enjoy the novel. I remember it struck me for not only being pessimistic but also having a pessimistic outlook on the human nature.